# Typedef nested structure in union, .c and .h file

Tags: c, struct, header-files, unions

How I should declare this union in header file?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "i2c_twi.h"

#define DS3231_ADDR 0xd0

typedef union {
    uint8_t bytes[7];
    struct{
         uint8_t ss;
         uint8_t mm;
         uint8_t hh;
         uint8_t dayOfWeek;
         uint8_t day;
         uint8_t month;
         uint8_t year;
     };
 } TDATETIME;

 TDATETIME dateTime;
```

I declare it this way and I can't use `dataTime` in my main function:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef DS3231_H_
#define DS3231_H_

typedef union _TDATETIME TDATETIME

#endif /* DS3231_H_ */
```

Compiler generates the following error:

```
../main.c:42:26: error: ‘dateTime’ undeclared (first use in this function)
DS3231_get_dateTime( &dateTime );
```

Comment: Where are you defining that union? n a source file? Why not in the header file? And is the error message you show the *only* messages shown by the compiler?

Comment: `typedef union _TDATETIME TDATETIME` misses a `;` at the end.

Comment: I don't miss a ; at the end. I don't coppy it here by mistake.

It's full message shown by the compiler:

../main.c: In function ‘main’:
../main.c:42:26: error: ‘dateTime’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    DS3231_get_dateTime( &dateTime );
                          ^
../main.c:42:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [main.o]

Comment: Are you going to define `TDATETIME ` variables, or access members of union in main.c? If you do, you need to provide complete typedef in header.

Comment: What file is the first code snippet from?

Comment: No, in main.c I invoke functions like:
DS3231_get_dateTime( &dateTime );

DS3231_get_dateTime(TDATETIME * dt); is  defined in this same file as union.

Comment: First snippet is from DS3131.c

Comment: @santiag Does DS3131.h contain `extern TDATETIME dateTime;`? You cannot use global variable from other compilation unit, unless main.c has at least extern declaration for it.

Comment: Okey, but how i should declare typedef union in .h? Declarations of another function has to know what is TDATETIME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your header file has is this:

```
typedef union _TDATETIME TDATETIME;
```

That just sets up the typedef, but does not define the union.  You need to define both the union and the typedef that goes with it.  Also, if there's a variable of this type that you want to use across multiple files, place an `extern` declaration for that variable in the header file, then define it in one C file:

In ds3231.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef DS3231_H_
#define DS3231_H_

typedef union {
    uint8_t bytes[7];

    struct{
         uint8_t ss;
         uint8_t mm;
         uint8_t hh;
         uint8_t dayOfWeek;
         uint8_t day;
         uint8_t month;
         uint8_t year;
     };
 } TDATETIME;

 extern TDATETIME dateTime;

#endif /* DS3231_H_ */
```

In ds3221.c:

```
#include "ds3221.h"

TDATETIME dateTime;
```

In main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ds3221.h"

int main()
{
    ...
    // use dateTime
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would seem that `dateTime` is in DS3131.c, so you probably should add part about `extern`ing it.

Comment: But I have 3 files. main.c DS3231.c and DS3231.h. Second and Third are library files. I must have TDATETIME dateTime; in DS3231.c. When I have typedef union in .h file I have this same error.

Comment: @santiag In that case you need to put an `extern` declaration in the DS3231.h, and the definition in DS3231.c.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> In C, you must use the union keyword to declare a union variable. In
>   C++, the union keyword is unnecessary:

```
union TDATETIME dateTime;
```

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: But `TDATETIME` is a type-alias set up by `typedef`, so the `union` keyword is not needed.

Comment: It's worked when I had all functions in main.c and i had not union keyword.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?

1. `typedef union _TDATETIME TDATETIME;` **or** `typedef union TDATETIME _TDATETIME;`
2. if the struct below in the header file, then **"TDATETIME dateTime"** should in the **.c file.**

   typedef union {

   ...
    } 
   DATETIME;

for your infomation